# c# Implicitly typed arrays behind the scenes

Tags: c#, arrays, declaration, implicit, typed

Can someone explain how the compiler proceeds here to find the "common" type (double).
I assume the IConvertible plays a role here?

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var nrColl = new[] { 1, 2, 0.14, 'a',};
}
```

Comment: `0.14` is a `double`, and all the others are integral values (including the `char`) convertible to `double`. What other common type do you think was an option ?

Comment: Hi @wohlstad , I did not expect another type. As shingo mentioned, I read microsoft specification before asked the question here with the intention to understand how the logic works to find a common type for several given types. But didn't understand in fully or found the right spots. I was looking into the char defintion and asked myself "where are these implicit conversion defintion from char to double??" The explanation from Sweeper and Lukas helped me to find the right spots in the documentation and to understand it a bit better than before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Finding the best common type of a set of expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#126315-finding-the-best-common-type-of-a-set-of-expressions) in the specification.

> - A new unfixed type variable X is introduced.
> - For each expression Ei an output type inference is performed from it to X.
> - X is fixed, if possible, and the resulting type is the best common type.
> - Otherwise inference fails.

> Intuitively this inference is equivalent to calling a method void M(X x₁ ... X xᵥ) with the Eᵢ as arguments and inferring X.

If you follow the steps of how an output type inference is done, you will eventually see that in this case the type variable `X` will have the lower bounds `int`, `double`, and `char`.

Then, to [*fix*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#126312-fixing) `X`,

> For each lower bound U of Xᵢ all types Uₑ to which there is not an implicit conversion from U are removed from the candidate set.
>
> If among the remaining candidate types Uₑ there is a unique type V to which there is an implicit conversion from all the other candidate types, then Xᵢ is fixed to V.

We can try to do that manually.

Let's first examine `int`. `int` can be implicitly converted to `double`, so `double` is not removed. `int` cannot be converted to `char`, so `char` is removed. Next we will examine `double`. `double` cannot be implicitly converted to `int`, so `int` is removed. We are now only left with `double`, and so `X` is fixed to `double`.

Basically, if there is exactly one type `T` in the types of the expressions in the array initialiser, that all the other expressions can be implicitly converted to, then `T` is the type of the array.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because every type you give it here is implicitly convertable to a double.
When you try to change the char (`'a'`) to a string (`"a"`) you'll notice that it won't work anymore. This is because a character in .Net is nothing more than a UInt16 with some additional methods and different Overrides (for example `ToString`) and it defines a implicit conversion to double.

Here is a example:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var bar = new[] { 1, 2, 0.14, 'a', new Foo(42)};
}

public class Foo
{
    public Foo(int value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    private int _value;

    public static implicit operator double(Foo foo)
    {
        return foo._value;
    }
}
```

Interestingly this also works if no direct implicit operator exists, but a chain of multiple implicit operators exists.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var bar = new[] { 1, 2, 0.14, 'a', new Foo(42)};
}

public class Foo
{
    public Foo(int value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    private int _value;

    public static implicit operator int(Foo foo)
    {
        return foo._value;
    }
}
```

But this 'conversion chaining' only seems to work with internal types for some reason.

This doesn't work:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var bar = new[] { 1, 2, 0.14, 'a', new Foo(42)};
}

public class Bar
{
    public Bar(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public int Value { get; set; }
    public static implicit operator double(Bar bar) => bar.Value;
}

public class Foo
{
    public Foo(int value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    private int _value;

    public static implicit operator Bar(Foo foo)
    {
        return new Bar(foo._value);
    }
}
```

Comment: "But this 'conversion chaining' only seems to work with internal types for some reason." Yes, a user-defined implicit conversion can optionally start and/or end with a "standard" implicit conversion.